# How can next.js render components into json format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We're migrating from a server side rendered approach with Java to a hybrid approach with React. For this we build endpoints into a express server, which render our React components with `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream` and deliver the output to another service which includes the components into it's DOM.

When looking forward it would be nice to use technologies like next.js.

Is there a way to output rendered components/pages by next.js in a JSON format? Or is it restricted to html? This would be every helpful specially in scenarios where you can't migrate a page in one shot.